# Same Dependency property, Multiple classes

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, dependency-properties

Visual Studio has thrown a useless exception which I think is caused by the fact I have multiple dependency properties in two similar classes with the same name.

The classes are add/edit contact so they share a number of properties, my problem is this.

I can register a property as:

```
DependencyProperty.Register( /*...*/ );
```

or:

```
MyDP.AddOwner( /*...*/ )
```

The problem is that I have no way of knowing whether the add or edit class will be instantiated first (depends on user choice), since they're defined as static, I can't put anything fancy in their initialisation logic... I'm out of ideas that can be self contained within the 2 classes.

So how do I set up the dependency properties in this scenario?

**Edit:**

> Type Initialization Exception: The type initializer for 'CharterHouseTouchScreenDemo.Views.Membership.AddMembershipView' threw an exception.

I know that it's one of the dependency property initialisers because when stepping through it doesn't even get to the constructor.

also, in this case, they don't share enough similarities to be the same class. in a nutshell, the only thing they share is the information stored in this dependency property.

**Edit 2:**

I'm suprised this isn't better documented, in any medium-large scale applications the chances of accidentally naming a dependency property the same thing are pretty large. Especially for generic things like `BackgroundColour`, `HeadingText`, `CurrentXYZ`...

I always assumed you passed the type of the owner class so that it wouldn't cause issues like this.

Comment: First, what is the "useless exception?"  That's the important piece to getting an answer.

Comment: Also, why separate classes?  If they share functionality, is there a reason to duplicate the work?  Not only is that doubling the work you do now (and causing these kinds of problems), it will potentially be a maintenance nightmare (for instance, if you find a bug, you have to remember to change it twice).  You may be better off with a single class, or if you really need separate classes, having a third class with the shared functionality.  Depending on your design, it may be an abstract class or interface that the others derive from, or it may be a separate class that the other classes call.

Comment: Egads.  A TypeInitializationException is thrown when something breaks in static constructors (either the one you defined or the one the compiler creates).  It is a wrapper around the exception that is thrown that breaks the static constructor.  So TypeInitializationException.InnerException tells you exactly what broke.

Comment: 'SubscriptionTypes' property was already registered by 'EditMembershipView', wow, don't think I've ever had an informative innerException before. Unfortunately though it only tells me what I already sussed out through trial and error =/.

Comment: If you are getting that kind of error, why not name the DP's separate things in the separate classes?  You must know which class you are trying to register?

Comment: I already have, just curious for future applications. While it works now, it's not fixing the problem per se, just avoiding it. And it's messing with my beautiful naming conventions!! =p. Also as I put in the new edit (and since I'm developing a large scale app as part of a collaborative project) the chances of creating this issue again and it slipping through testing is fairly high. So I'm keen to find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a kosher answer, but it works:

```
#region SubscriptionFee

/// <summary>
/// SubscriptionFee Dependency Property
/// </summary>
public static readonly DependencyProperty SubscriptionFeeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register( "SubscriptionFee_2", typeof( decimal ), typeof( EditMembershipViewModel ),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( (decimal)0 ) );

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the SubscriptionFee property. This dependency property
/// indicates the new subscription fee for the customer.
/// </summary>
public decimal SubscriptionFee
{
    get { return (decimal)GetValue( SubscriptionFeeProperty ); }
    set { SetValue( SubscriptionFeeProperty, value ); }
}

#endregion SubscriptionFee
```

Answer (score 0):

First, sorry this isn't being posted as a comment. I don' tyet have the reputation to leave comments.

With classes named things like "AddContact and EditContact" it seems to me you are building these classes to edit what is probably a Contact class?

You may be going about your solution completely wrong and causing yourself a much bigger headache.

Can you give more details on the code? If, for example, you have a GUI that displays contact information and you wish to edit it, there are much better solutions than having Add/Edit classes. The depencey properties should be a part of your contact class rather than their own separate edit class.

Perhaps you may wish to read up on [Model View View-Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) and the [WPF command framework](http://www.devx.com/DevX/Article/37893/1954)

Spending a half hour reading up on these two topics may lead you to a much more elegant solution that is less of a hastle for you.

Comment: Contacts are stored in a database which is accessed through a web-service, which is built o the principles of a design pattern (which for the life of me I can't remember the name of)

anyway.. it's accessed by filling in command classes which are sent to the service, the UpdateContactCommand and CreateContactCommand are programmatically entirely isolated, while they share the same property names. Hence separating create and edit Contact classes (p.s. there are advantages to the service, just not really coming across here...)